# Python command to open a raw TCP/IP session

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, tcp, putty

I have tried searching and got the following command to be run from command line:

```
putty.exe -raw *ip* *port*
```

Is there any other way to open a raw session using Python without having a dependency on PuTTY, MTPuTTY or any other 3rd party application/tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```